# Invalid argument: permission.value：method addeditors

Tags: google-apps-script

Error Exception: Invalid argument: permission.value

I guess if it's because data(two emails) exceed the array.

Logger(data_arr) result is as follows：
[[get drive ID, 1gCXwpREH8doX9btKY_rrQyrSep7H63NFhMEe2xLw5pw, , , ], [spread sheet3, 1yyr6edKuRekWQydINNgZb6g_Sw4BYOK1OAfLWo9L1D8, kxexxx91@gmail.com,tongxxxa@gmail.com, , ], [spread sheet2, 1yR4ELipZ2NSnzccMI8ebDP7K3N7oqavPEvfdYfD7CCI, , , ]]

Please give me some tweaking suggestions to add multiple editors.

sorry for my language,and thanks for your help.

---

### full code

```
function addUsers(){
  // Read Data from sheet
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Logger.log(sheet)
  let range = sheet.getRange(3,1,3,5);
  //Logger.log(range)
  let data_arr =  range.getValues();
  Logger.log(data_arr)
  for (data of data_arr){
    let file_ID = data[1];
    let editors_mail_arr = data[2];
    let viewers_mail_arr = data[3];
    let commenters_mail_arr = data[4];
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_ID);
    if(editors_mail_arr!=[]) file.addEditors([editors_mail_arr]);
    if(viewers_mail_arr!=[]) file.addViewers([viewers_mail_arr]);
    if(commenters_mail_arr!=[]) file.addCommenters([commenters_mail_arr]);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ // Your provided data.
  ["get drive ID", ID, , , ], 
  ["spread sheet3", ID, "email1,email2", , ], 
  ["spread sheet2", ID, , , ]
]
```

Although you're properly passing a String[] to these methods, you will need to pass them in as `["string1", "string2"]`; currently they are `["string1,string2"]`.

**A simple fix would be to rewrite:**

```
let editors_mail_arr = data[2];
let viewers_mail_arr = data[3];
let commenters_mail_arr = data[4];
// ...
if(editors_mail_arr!=[]) file.addEditors([editors_mail_arr]);
if(viewers_mail_arr!=[]) file.addViewers([viewers_mail_arr]);
if(commenters_mail_arr!=[]) file.addCommenters([commenters_mail_arr]);
```

**To:**

```
let editors_mail_arr = data[2].split(`,`);
let viewers_mail_arr = data[3].split(`,`);
let commenters_mail_arr = data[4].split(`,`);
// ...
if(editors_mail_arr.length) file.addEditors(editors_mail_arr);
if(viewers_mail_arr.length) file.addViewers(viewers_mail_arr);
if(commenters_mail_arr.length) file.addCommenters(commenters_mail_arr);
```

This is assuming data is split as `user1,user2` as shown in your provided example.

Resource:

- [.addEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditorsemailaddresses)
- [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: thanks for tou reply,but it's still cant work

Comment: I tried logger.log(data_arr),and there send back the information"[[get drive ID, 1gCXwpREH8doX9btKY_rrQyrSep7H63NFhMEe2xLw5pw, , , ], [spread sheet3, 1yyr6edKuRekWQydINNgZb6g_Sw4BYOK1OAfLWo9L1D8, ABC@gmail.com,CDE@gmail.com, , ], [spread sheet2, 1yR4ELipZ2NSnzccMI8ebDP7K3N7oqavPEvfdYfD7CCI, , , ]]"

And  "Exception: Invalid argument: permission.value addUsers @ readFiles.gs:90" message.

Comment: Can you please post your code at line 90 of readFile.gs? `readFiles.gs:90`

Comment: Sure
90     if(editors_mail_arr.length) file.addEditors(editors_mail_arr);

Comment: And lastly, add `Logger.log(editors_mail_arr)` above this line and see what it says please